# How to add dropdown checkboxes in a jQuery table?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have created a website mainly using HTML, CSS, PHP and MYSQL. I have successfully gotten tabledit working on the site, but I am not sure how to add the functionality for dropdown checkboxes. I need it to show as checked if the user has the role and when unchecked to update the MySQL table. Are dropdown checkboxes something that can be implemented with this plugin?

This is how the HTML is set up:

ModifyUser.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Modifying Users</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/assets/js/tabledit.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        #sample_data tr > *:nth-child(1) {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h3 align="center">Modifying Users</h3>
    <br />
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <!--        <div class="panel-heading">Sample Data</div>-->
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="sample_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Approval</th>
                        <th>Roles</th> // COLUMN THAT SHOULD HAVE DROPDOWN CHECKBOX
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var dataTable = $('#sample_data').DataTable({
            "processing" : true,
            "serverSide" : true,
            "order" : [],
            "ajax" : {
                url:"FetchUserTable.php",
                type:"POST"
            }
        });

        $('#sample_data').on('draw.dt', function(){
            $('#sample_data').Tabledit({
                url:'ActionUserTable.php',
                dataType:'json',
                columns:{
                    identifier : [0, 'user_id'],
                    editable:[
                        [1, 'first_name'],
                        [2, 'last_name'],
                        [3, 'email'],
                        [4, 'admin_approved', '{"1":"Approved","2":"Disapproved"}']
                        [5, 'role_id'] // THIS SHOULD BE AN EDITABLE DROPDOWN CHECKBOX
                    ]
                },
                restoreButton:false,
                onSuccess:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    if(data.action == 'delete')
                    {
                        $('#' + data.id).remove();
                        $('#sample_data').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does this give you an ideas?  https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/snqw56dw/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58345486/jquery-tabledit-dropdown-is-it-possible-to-retrieve-values-from-mysql-database

Comment: @natel Not really. My problem is with how my table is written. I was able to implement a checkbox with a table <thead></thead> & <tbody></tbody>, but no if the column values get feed from an array as in this case.

Comment: Does this help?  https://jsfiddle.net/v2quhwb8/2/ and/or this http://jsfiddle.net/9chxhmk2/